# ¿Cómo crear un String a partir de un array de char?

Tags: java, string, eclipse, variables

Estoy intentando inicializar una variable de tipo String a partir de un array de char que tengo.
Estos son los valores que contiene el array alfanumericos.

```
private static char alfanumericos[] = new char[36];

//se añaden los caracteres alfanumericos
static {
    alfanumericos[0]='a';
    alfanumericos[1]='b';
    alfanumericos[2]='c';
    alfanumericos[3]='d';
    alfanumericos[4]='e';
    alfanumericos[5]='f';
    alfanumericos[6]='g';
    alfanumericos[7]='h';
    alfanumericos[8]='i';
    alfanumericos[9]='j';
    alfanumericos[10]='k';
    alfanumericos[11]='l';
    alfanumericos[12]='m';
    alfanumericos[13]='n';
    alfanumericos[14]='ñ';
    alfanumericos[15]='o';
    alfanumericos[16]='p';
    alfanumericos[17]='q';
    alfanumericos[18]='r';
    alfanumericos[19]='s';
    alfanumericos[20]='t';
    alfanumericos[21]='u';
    alfanumericos[22]='v';
    alfanumericos[23]='w';
    alfanumericos[24]='x';
    alfanumericos[25]='y';
    alfanumericos[26]='z';
    alfanumericos[27]='1';
    alfanumericos[28]='2';
    alfanumericos[29]='3';
    alfanumericos[30]='4';
    alfanumericos[31]='5';
    alfanumericos[32]='6';
    alfanumericos[33]='7';
    alfanumericos[34]='8';
    alfanumericos[35]='9';
    alfanumericos[36]='0';
}
```

Y quiero formar una palabra a partir del contenido del array, que guardaré en la variable `palabra`. Es esta instrucción la que me da error.

```
String palabra=alfanumericos[7]+alfanumericos[15]+alfanumericos[11]+alfanumericos[0];
```

En cambio si hago lo siguiente:

```
String palabra=alfanumericos[7]+alfanumericos[15]+alfanumericos[11]+alfanumericos[0]+"";
```

Lo da como válido. ¿Por qué me obliga a poner un espacio?

Comment: ¿No es mas sencillo y optimo, utilizar el código **ASCII**? Veo innecesario crear un Array para esto

Comment: si te ha servido la respuesta, por favor, márcala como aceptada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que está pasando es que el método para imprimir por pantalla que estás utilizando requiere que le pases como parámetro una variable de tipo `String`.

Al añadirle la cadena vacia `""`, basicamente lo que estás haciendo es forzar una conversión a `String` de los parámetros que pasas al método.

Si no quieres hacer eso, tu otra opción sería usar `Character.toString(myChar);` para cada char que quieras imprimir.

```
String palabra = Character.toString(alfanumericos[7]) + Character.toString(alfanumericos[15]) + Character.toString(alfanumericos[11]) + Character.toString(alfanumericos[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Para que interprete que quieres concatenar caracteres tienes que añadirle un string, o sino lo tomará como un int debido a que cambiará el valor del char a ASCII.

```
System.out.println("" + char1 + char2 + char3...);
```

Además, el array tiene una longitud de 36. Esto te dará un error.

```
alfanumericos[36]='0';
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo implementaría así:

```
    char[] caracteres
          = new char[] {alfanumericos[7],alfanumericos[15],alfanumericos[11],alfanumericos[0]};
    String texto = new String(caracteres);
```